# How does a stock market work under a command economy

Tags: macroeconomics, stock-market

If a central government owns the means of production and controls business, what ramifications does that have on a stock market? Under such an economy are shares still traded as they are in a mixed/market economy? What about securities?

Comment: What do shares do if they do not control production and business? This seems like an unclear speculative set up.